# jQuery Mobile prefetch page automatically

Tags: jquery, mobile, prefetch

I need to add a preloading page to my JQM project. I figured the best way to do this was by using the JQM Prefetch function on the preloading page and get it to fire once the prefetched(home page) page was loaded.

Here is the code am using. Do I need to add an instance to get this to work as I am not sure where to add the url(home.html)? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

HTML

```
<head>
<script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/custom.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.2.0-rc.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Custom.js

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
$.mobile.loadPage( pageUrl, { showLoadMsg: false } );
});
```